# Java Map to JSON { "key":"value","key1":"value1"} as "key":value, "key1":"value1" using Jackson

Tags: java, java-8, jackson

I have a Sample pojo that has a Map

```
class Sample {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private Map<String,Object> map;
  public Map<String,Object> getMap() {
    return map;
  }
  public void setMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
    this.map = map;
  }
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

When I write this POJO as JSON using Jackson, I get the following results.

```
{
  "id" : 1234,
  "name" : "abc",
  "map" : {
    "key1" : {
       "field" : "value",
       "field1" : "value"
    },
    "key2" : [
       {
          "something" : "a",
          "somethingElse" : 1
       },
       {
          "something" : "b",
          "somethingElse" : 2
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

while I would like to have this map written as

```
{
  "id" : 1234,
  "name" : "abc",
  "key1" : {
       "field" : "value",
       "field1" : "value"
  },
  "key2" : [
     {
        "something" : "a",
        "somethingElse" : 1
     },
     {
        "something" : "b",
        "somethingElse" : 2
     }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to this WITHOUT using custom serializer?

Comment: Why do you have wrapper class for your Map. Can't you directly serialize the Map to get the JSON you're after?

Comment: So you just want to get rid of the outer `"map":{ ...}`? In that case just serialize the map itself, not the wrapper. If that wrapper happens to contain other fields as well though, you'd better not remove that "map" level.

Comment: @Thomas Yes I want to get rid of the "map": {...}. And I am exploring options other than a custom serializer, like mixin or a propertyNamingStrategy of Jackon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use Jackson, than following code can help you:

```
class Sample {

  private Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String,Object> getMap() {
    return this.map;
  }
  public void setMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
    this.map = map;
  }
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void addValue(String key, Object value) {
    this.map.put(key, value);
  }
}
```

In this case for all unknow fields this will store (or obtain) values by theirs keys.